# way to execute different folders' scripts using one bat file from one location

Tags: batch-file, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

I have to execute a bulk of scripts on sql server 2008r2.These scripts are present in many folders and subfolders.I created a batch file to execute these scripts but my problem is i have to put this bat file in a folder to execute the concerned folder's scripts.So, if there are more than 10 folders so i have to put it this bat file 10 times in a folder.Is there any way so that i can put my bat file just once wherever i want(like on desktop) and execute the folder's files?

.bat file:-

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S %1 /d %2 -E   -i"%%G" pause
```

Passing server name and database name using command prompt.

Comment: Do these folders change or are they constant?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `/R` option to the `FOR` to search recursively:

```
FOR /R . %%G IN (*.sql) DO ... etc ...
```

That will search for *.sql files anywhere below the current directory (`.`).  Or make it `FOR /R C:\Folder %%G IN (*.sql) DO ...` if you want a specific folder as the root.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wish to execute yourbatasposted from multiple directories using the same servername and databasename,

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (folderlist.txt) DO (
PUSHD "%%i"
CALL yourbatasposted %*
POPD
)
```

where folderlist.txt is a simple textfile containing the target directory names, one to a line.

If you wish to control which servers/databases/directories are executed individually, then create controllist,txt formatted as lines of

servername database directory

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=Q" %%i IN (controllist.txt) DO (
PUSHD "%%k"
CALL yourbatasposted %%i %%j
POPD
)
```

Where "Q" is the delimiter between the columns in controllist.txt. Omit the delims= clause if you choose to use spaces.

Naturally, yourbatchasposted.bat should be located in any directory mentioned in the %path% variable...